# How to tell Visual Studio Code to follow Django itself source code while debugging Django applications?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, django-rest-framework

I have a Django application and I set Visual Studio Code to debug it using the default `launch.json` configuration. When I start the server (`manage.py runserver`) and make a request, VSCode stops at the first breakpoint (that is correct), but when I step into a function, VSCode never follows/shows Django source code itself and I would like to see what is happening inside that Django source code.

How could I configure VSCode to follow/show Django (and Django REST) source code while debugging Django applications?

**EDIT 2019-05-07**: With VSCode 1.33.1, the option `debugStdLib` is obsoleted and it has been replaced by `justMyCode`, that is exactly the opposite. So to debug Django code, `justMyCode` has to be set to `false` in `launch.json`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have debugging working, all you need to do is add the following setting into your `launch.json` file for the debug configuration used for `Django`:

```js
"debugStdLib": true,
```

This flag tells the Python debugger that you wish to debug standard library code.

E.g.:

```js
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "debugStdLib": true,
```

Comment: With VSCode 1.33.1 `debugStdLib` is obsoleted and has been replaced by `jusMyCode` that is exactly the opposite. But, of course, many thanks for your response :)